# Strange stripes in AirPort Utility window

Tags: macos, airport

What are this weird stripes in only this window (AirPort Utility) and can I get rid of them? Sometimes this bug does not appear, but most still it do. I thought it depends on the screen resolution, but I was mistaken. MBP retina late 2013, OS X 10.9.5. Thanks! [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

New system update 10.10.1 helped.